# Why constructor of a statically created object is not executed before main function if the object is defined in library?

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-variables, abstract-factory

I am trying to create "plugin" factory. When an user requests creation of an object factory queries it's child factories and picks suitable one to create the object.

Instances of child libraries are static objects. When they are created they register themselves to the top level factory.

Here is simplified version:

```
// ifactory.h
#ifndef _IFACTORY_H_
#define _IFACTORY_H_

#include <string>

class IFactory {
public:
    virtual int createNumber(const std::string& name, std::pair<int, int> range) = 0;

    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;

    virtual ~IFactory() = default;
};

#endif
```

```
// defaul_factory.h:
#ifndef _DEFAULT_FACTORY_H_
#define _DEFAULT_FACTORY_H_

#include "ifactory.h"

#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class DefaultFactory : public IFactory {
public:
    int createNumber(const std::string& name, std::pair<int, int> range) override {
        for (auto factory: g_factories) {
            if (factory->getName() == name) {
                return factory->createNumber(name, range);
            }
        }

        throw std::runtime_error{"No factory can create requested number"};
    }

    std::string getName() const override {
        return "default";
    }

    static void registerFactory(IFactory* factory) {
        g_factories.push_back(factory);
    }

private:
    static std::vector<IFactory*> g_factories;
};
#endif
```

```
// defalut_factory.cpp
#include "default_factory.h"

std::vector<IFactory*> DefaultFactory::g_factories;
```

```
// even_factory.cpp
#include "default_factory.h"

class EvenFactory : public IFactory {
public:
    EvenFactory() {
        DefaultFactory::registerFactory(this);
    }

    int createNumber(const std::string& name, std::pair<int, int> range) override {
        return range.first % 2 == 0 ? range.first + 4 : range.first + 3;
    }

    std::string getName() const override {
        return "even";
    }
};

// Hopefully registers itself to the default factory
static EvenFactory evenFactory;
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "default_factory.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    DefaultFactory factory;
    std::cout << factory.createNumber("even", {100, 200}) << std::endl;
}
```

```
# Makefile:
all: foo

foo: libdefault_factory.so libeven_factory.so main.cpp
    $(CXX) -L./ -o foo main.cpp -ldefault_factory -Wl,--no-as-needed -leven_factory

libdefault_factory.so: default_factory.cpp default_factory.h ifactory.h
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC -o libdefault_factory.so default_factory.cpp

libeven_factory.so: even_factory.cpp default_factory.h ifactory.h
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC -o libeven_factory.so even_factory.cpp

bar: default_factory.cpp even_factory.cpp default_factory.h ifactory.h main.cpp
    $(CXX) -o bar main.cpp default_factory.cpp even_factory.cpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm foo bar *.so
```

When I execute `foo` I get a runtime exception which is thrown from `DefalutFactory`, as if the constructor was not run for `evenFactory`.

Running `bar` prints `104`, as expected.

Why the constructor is not invoked for the `foo`?

NOTE: I tested the example with g++ version 9 and g++ version 10.2.

Comment: Explanation of a different mistake in the code: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301)

Comment: See [Deferred_dynamic_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Deferred_dynamic_initialization).

Comment: `-leven_factory` does nothing. No object outside of the library references anything from that library, so it is simply not linked. You want `-Wl,--no-as-needed` before `-leven_factory`. (Verify by running `ldd foo`). (I think --no-as-needed used to be the default but Ubuntu and probably others have recently changed that).

Comment: Welcome to the [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).  `evenFactory` may be constructed before `g_factories`.  C++ provides no guarantees about what order static objects in different translation units get initialized in.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, You are right, `even_factory` wasn't linked. I added `-Wl,--no-as-needed`, and according to `ldd` `foo` is now linked to `libeven_factory.so`. Behavior of `foo` is unchanged tho.

edit: My bad, the behavior did change. Constructor is invoked now, but it looks like it's invoked before `g_factories` is initialized as others pointed out.

Comment: So you also have the static initialization order fiasco on top of that. To fix it, replace g_factories with a function returning a function-local static object.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, Yup, now it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 AFAIK mainstream compilers on mainstream platforms don't do deferred initialisation, and if they start to, a lot of existing code will break. So they probably never will. Not by default at least.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_IFACTORY_H_`, `_DEFAULT_FACTORY_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: I think, the static vector from DefaultFactory  does not exist bevore DefaultFactory iis instantiated.